# Get post id in Post Page within Wp-admin

Tags: plugins, posts, wp-admin, post-meta

I want to get post ID within Post page. I need this for custom meta box so i can set the id in shortcode. I can show the result in notices but don't know how to make it global to use for meta input. What i got till now is :

```
function foo(){
global $post;
$nid = $post->ID;
var_dump($nid);
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'foo' );
```

which show the id but i need it as a variable so i can use it later. so i tried to make `$nid` global then echo it but it show nothing.

Comment: Please share the meta box code.

Comment: How are you echoing it? `echo $nid;` or `echo $GLOBALS["nid"]`?

Comment: tried both with lo luck.

Comment: Solved the problem with `get_the_ID()` within meta box.

Answer (score -3):

use get_the_ID() to get post id

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?